# Best way to search a word in large log files (100GB) in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, executorservice, large-files, logfile, response-time

I am analyzing mail logs. Each mail has a unique id and specific information. I have to search this id in another type of log so I can fully analyze and extract this mail information.

I am using `BufferReader` and `executorService` which execute tasks in asynchronous mode using threads but my response time isn't as quick as I want.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419909/is-a-question-asking-for-good-ways-to-do-something-really-opinion-based

Comment: What about building an index?

Comment: What about using a database

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Danny_ds When you edit, try to fix *all* the problems in the post, not just one or two. Edit reverted and then improved.